# FireFox doesn't switch to a non-angular popup window by Webdriver JS (via Protractor)

Tags: javascript, node.js, webdriver, jasmine, protractor

i can't switch windows during my testing by Selenium Webdriver using Jasmine JS

On FireFox browser (latest v)

Runner: Protractor JS

Platform: Selenium Webdriver on Node.JS

Code framework: Jasmine JS

**The code is below:**

```
describe('LiveSite Portal - Client pay by PayPal', function() {

afterEach(function () {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
});

it('Client LiveSite - Payments - Perform a payment', function () {
    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

    browser.get("https://www.vcita.com/v/bungee/home");

    var makePayment = element(by.xpath("//div[@class='actions-row']//a[.='Make Payment']"));
    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(makePayment), 5000);
    makePayment.click();

    var amount = element(by.name("amount"));
    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(amount), 5000);
    amount.sendKeys("1");

    captureScreen("paymentForm");
    browser.sleep(3000);

    element(by.name("pay_for")).sendKeys("Mister Bungee");
    element(by.name("notes")).sendKeys("Please approve my payments. Thanks a lot, Dr. Kugler. +972545453435");
    element(by.name("email")).sendKeys("idanvcita@gmail.com");
    element(by.name("first_name")).click();

    browser.sleep(5000);
    element(by.xpath("//button[. = 'Continue']")).click();
    browser.sleep(2000);
    captureScreen("PaymentContinueToPayment");
    browser.sleep(3000);
    element(by.xpath("//button[. = 'Continue to Payment']")).click();

    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
        browser.switchTo().window(handles[1]);

        var loadLogin = element(by.id("loadLogin"));
        browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(loadLogin), 15000);

        loadLogin.click();
    });

    expect (browser.driver.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('www.paypal.com');

    element(by.id("loadLogin")).click();
    browser.driver.sleep(3000);
    element(by.id("login_email")).sendKeys("test2@vcita.com");
    element(by.id("login_password")).sendKeys("nhynh2011");
    browser.driver.sleep(1000);
    element(by.id("submitLogin")).click();
    browser.driver.sleep(10000);

    element(by.id("submit.x")).click();
    browser.driver.sleep(15000);

    browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
        browser.switchTo().window(handles[0]);
    });
});

it('Client LiveSite - Payments - Payment Succeed', function () {
    expect (browser.driver.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('vcita.com/v/');

    captureScreen("PaymentSucceed");
    browser.driver.sleep(3000);
    element (by.css("a.btn")).click();
    browser.driver.sleep(2000);
});

});
```

Is anyone know what is wrong with this? It works fine on Chrome.

**The error from Protractor is below:**

```
  Failures:

  1) LiveSite Portal - Client pay by PayPal Client LiveSite - Payments - Perform
 a payment
   Message:
     NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.id("loadLogin")
   Stacktrace:
     NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.id("loadLogin")
    at new bot.Error (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\
node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\error.js:113:18)
    at C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:
706:15
    at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runInFrame_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Ro
aming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\
promise.js:1877:20)
    at [object Object].promise.Callback_.goog.defineClass.notify (C:\Users\idan\
AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\
webdriver\promise.js:2464:25)
    at [object Object].promise.Promise.notify_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\np
m\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.
js:563:12)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.goog.array.forEach (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\array\array.js:203:43)
    at [object Object].promise.Promise.notifyAll_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming
\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promi
se.js:552:16)
    at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m
odules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\run.js:125:21)
    at runMicrotasksCallback (node.js:337:7)
Error
    at [object Object].ElementArrayFinder.applyAction_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Ro
aming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:403:21)
    at [object Object].self.(anonymous function) [as click] (C:\Users\idan\AppDa
ta\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:76:19)
    at [object Object].self.(anonymous function) [as click] (C:\Users\idan\AppDa
ta\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:733:11)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (c:\automation\tests\payments.js:48:37)
    at C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\ja
sminewd\index.js:94:14
    at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runInFrame_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Ro
aming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\
promise.js:1877:20)
    at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runEventLoop_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\
Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdrive
r\promise.js:1755:8)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul
es\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:2056:12)
    at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m
odules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\run.js:125:21)
From: Task: Asynchronous test function: it()
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul
es\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd\index.js:93:33)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul
es\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\async-callback.js:45:37)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Block.execute (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\
node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:1174:1
7)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Queue.next_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\no
de_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2209:31)

    at [object Object]._onTimeout (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module
s\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2199:18)
Error
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (c:\automation\tests\payments.js:8:5)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Env.describe_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\
node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:913:21
)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Env.describe (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\n
ode_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:898:15)

    at describe (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_
modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:658:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\automation\tests\payments.js:2:1)

  2) LiveSite Portal - Client pay by PayPal Client LiveSite - Payments - Payment
 Succeed
   Message:
     Expected 'https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?dispatch=5885d80a13c0db1
f8e263663d3faee8d99e4111b56ef0eae45e68b8988f5b2dd' to contain 'vcita.com/v/'.
   Stacktrace:
     Error: Failed expectation
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (c:\automation\tests\payments.js:67:49)
    at C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\ja
sminewd\index.js:94:14
    at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runInFrame_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Ro
aming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\
promise.js:1877:20)
    at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runEventLoop_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\
Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdrive
r\promise.js:1755:8)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul
es\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:2056:12)
    at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m
odules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\run.js:125:21)
    at runMicrotasksCallback (node.js:337:7)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)

  3) LiveSite Portal - Client pay by PayPal Client LiveSite - Payments - Payment
 Succeed
   Message:
     Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "angular could no
t be found on the window"
   Stacktrace:
     undefined
```

Comment: Please your help chief! @alecxe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Structure your code to wait for `loadLogin` to become visible before clicking it. Also, switch to the last handle in the list of available handles (Firefox handles tabs/windows differently):

```
browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {      
    browser.switchTo().window(handles[handles.length - 1]);

    var loadLogin = element(by.id("loadLogin"));
    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(loadLogin), 15000);

    expect(browser.driver.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('www.paypal.com');

    loadLogin.click();
    browser.driver.sleep(3000);
    element(by.id("login_email")).sendKeys("test2@vcita.com");
    element(by.id("login_password")).sendKeys("nhynh2011");
    browser.driver.sleep(1000);
    element(by.id("submitLogin")).click();
    browser.driver.sleep(10000);

    element(by.id("submit.x")).click();
    browser.driver.sleep(15000);

    browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
        browser.switchTo().window(handles[0]);
    });
});
```

Comment: @IdanE what are the symptoms?

Comment: It's the same error :/ I just added all the rest of the script ibside tge fubction of "then" @alecxe

Comment: @IdanE ah, sure, gotcha. I think I know what the problem is.